# Understanding the Address and its members

Tags: solidity, addresses, address.transfer

I am new to ethereum blockchain and solidity. I am trying to understand "Address" and its member from the [link](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#value-types) . In the below example The "transfer" will transfer from which address to which address ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per example

```
address x = 0x123;
address myAddress = this;
if (x.balance < 10 && myAddress.balance >= 10) x.transfer(10);
```

`myAddress` is `this` (so a contract). `x` is a specific address. So the transfer function will transfer the money from the contract balance to the `x`'s address. In case `x` is also contract, this statement will apply (from the doc):

> If x is a contract address, its code (more specifically: its fallback
>   function, if present) will be executed together with the transfer call
>   (this is a feature of the EVM and cannot be prevented). If that
>   execution runs out of gas or fails in any way, the Ether transfer will
>   be reverted and the current contract will stop with an exception.